# In Multisite the users profile picture keeps disappearing for "the other site"

Tags: multisite, profiles

I have the following setup: **Site A** with **Domain A** and **Site B** with **Domain B**

**Site A** is set to be the main site.

The users' profile pictures have all been set via **Site A** and therefore **Domain A**.
They do show under "**Network Admin** > Users", but they don't show under "**Site B** > Users".

If I now set an image for profile XYZ under "**Site B** > Users", the URL for that profile pic changes to **Domain B** in the users table and there is no image anymore displayed for profile XYZ under **Network Admin** nor under **Site A**.

Any idea what the issue might be and is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the handling of profile pictures/avatars with the plugin "Simple Local Avatars" and it might be soon addressed: https://github.com/10up/simple-local-avatars/issues/26#issuecomment-814157532